# Sort Bootstrap-Vue table (mon, tue, wed instead of alphabetical)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a table that pulls information from a database using Bootstrap-vue.  The database has a field called "day" which stores a string value of "mon", "tue", "wed", etc.  I want to be able to sort the table by this column by day, rather than alphabetically.  Is there a way to do this?

I'm pretty new to Vue and Bootstrap Vue.  I've set up the table, and it pulls the information from the Database just fine.  It stores each as an object, and displays it according to defined fields.

Simplified code to visualize problem:

HTML:

```html
<div id='root'>
   <b-container fluid>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <br/>
      <b-table
         show-empty
         stacked="md"
         :items="tableItems"
         :fields="fields"
         sort-by="day"
      >
      </b-table>
   </b-container>
</div>
```

Vue:

```
new Vue({
el: '#root',
data() {
   return {
      tableItems: [
         {name: 'Mark', age: '23', day:'wed'},
         {name: 'John', age: '21', day:'thu'},
         {name: 'Stephen', age: '24', day:'tue'},
         {name: 'Will', age: '31', day:'fri'},
         {name: 'Andrew', age: '27', day:'wed'},
         {name: 'James', age: '24', day:'mon'},
         {name: 'Shawn', age: '29', day:'tue'},
      ],
      fields: [
         { key: 'name', label: 'Name', sortable: true},
         { key: 'age', label: 'Age', sortable: true, class: 'text-center' },
         { key: 'day', label: 'Day', sortable: true},
      ],
      }
   }
});
```

Currently this code will sort alphabetically in the day column.  I'd like it to sort by "date", e.g. "mon", "tue", "wed", etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your own custom sort method by hooking into the `:sort-compare` routine.

```
  <b-table
     show-empty
     stacked="md"
     :items="tableItems"
     :fields="fields"
     :sort-compare="sortingChanged"
  >
```

Then define a dictionary to give your days values.

```
const days = {
  "sun": 0,
  "mon": 1,
  "tue": 2,
  "wed": 3,
  "thu": 4,
  "fri": 5,
  "sat": 6,
};
```

and finally handle the sorting.

```
  methods: {
    sortingChanged(a, b, key) {
      let result = 0;
      if (key === 'day') {
          let day1 = a[key].toLowerCase();
          let day2 = b[key].toLowerCase();
          return days[day1] - days[day2];
      } 
      return false;
    }
  }
```

The Math.min/max stuff is to clamp the value between -1 and 1 which the `sort-compare` routine requires to work properly.

Here's a [working codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-2je6c).  You can read more about the `sort-compare` routine in the [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#sort-compare-routine).

Thanks to @TroyMorehouse for pointing out a better approach.

Comment: If you use a custom sort-compare routine, you can have it only handle the sorting for particular fields.  If you want b-table's internal sort to handle certain fields, just return `false` or `null` from the sort-compare routine and it will fall back to the internal sort routine for that filed key.

Comment: @TroyMorehouse that's a much better approach that I didn't see previously.  I updated my answer to show this approach instead.

Comment: @Steven B Note you shouldn't use `sortDesc` to control negative/positive sorting (b-table does that for you internally). `sortDesc` is only there if you need to handle sorting nulls (or empty) to the top or bottom of the list)  So remove the `if (sortDesc) { ... }` part. I have edited your answer to remove the `if` statement

Comment: Also it is not required to clamp the return value between `-1` and `+1`, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: @TroyMorehouse seems like you should have answered this question lol.  I accepted the edit.